# How to use Twitter Api to grab the number of twitter followers I have?

Tags: api, twitter

I want to use twitter api to grab the number of twitter followers I have and logs that information. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Check out twitters [REST API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) -- it's generally quite good.

In your case, what you want to do to start is

```
GET /followers/ids.json?screen_name=<your screen name goes here>&cursor=-1
```

This will return a JSON document with the first 5000 followers in it. You can count the number of items in the 'ids' array. If there are more pages of results, the 'next_cursor' key will be non-zero. If so, use that as the 'cursor' argument and call the API again. Repeat until you have found all of the followers.

Comment: Thank you.  I have found a way to do that.

Comment: @Ian Clelland, I want to get the followers for a specific twitter user, can you please guide me, here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script